# How to solve cargo container exception

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-3, maven-cargo

I'm trying to start a standalone apache tomcat 5.5 container with cargo plug-in, but i get the following error:

```
[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] Checking URL [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] for status using a timeout of [120000] ms...
[DEBUG] [URLDeployableMonitor] URL [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html] is not responding: -1 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

this is my cargo configuration:

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat5x</containerId>
                    <home>C:\Users\user\tomcat</home>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <home>target/tomcat5x</home>
                    <files>
                        ... a few files to copy
                    </files>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Correct port or is this port already occupied by an other instace of whatever ` is not responding: -1 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`. Can you show the full pom file?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same exception when I realized that I was using https instead of http as protocol. Changing the protocol to http solved the issue for me. I hope it helps you and also anyone who might have missed this subtlety.

Comment: Which Maven config setting have u changed?